Syncfusion Xamarin Signature Pad
So I have a page that changes dynamically based on wether or not the user pressed a button/selected a object from the dropdown.
The problem I am experiencing is that the signature pad isn't showing up when the bool property changes to true.
Here is the part of the viewmodel that changes the variable for the Xamarin page:
private void LoadCaptureViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName != nameof(SelectedStatus)) return;

    try
    {
        if (SelectedStatus == null)
            return;

        CurrentLoad = new Load()
        {
            id = Guid.NewGuid(),
            LoadType = "Inbound"
        };
        var newStatus = new Status()
        {

            Id = SelectedStatus.Id,
            Name = SelectedStatus.Name
        };
        CurrentLoad.CurrentStatus = newStatus;
        SelectedStatus = newStatus;

        CurrentLoad.currentStatusId = SelectedStatus.Id;

        //StateChangeEventArgs(newStatus);

        if (CurrentLoad.LoadType == "Inbound")
        {
            IsBinCapturingVisible = true;
            SignaturePadVisible = false;
        }

        SignaturePadVisible = SelectedStatus?.Id == AwaitingPODGuid;

        if (SelectedStatus.Id == LoadCompleteGuid)
        {
            //Should Not Be Able To Edit anything on the page
            IsEnabled = false;
            OdometerReadingVisible = true;
        }
        else if (SelectedStatus.Id == AwaitingPODGuid)
        {
            SignaturePadVisible = true;
            IsEnabled = true;
            OdometerReadingVisible = true;

            ProofOfDelivery = new ProofOfDelivery()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                LoadId = CurrentLoad.id,
                SignedOn = DateTime.Today,
                ProofOfDeliveryUrl = ""
            };
        }
        else if (SelectedStatus.Id == OffLaodODOGuid)
        {
            SignaturePadVisible = false;
            IsEnabled = true;
            OdometerReadingVisible = true;
        }
        else if (SelectedStatus.Id == InboundOffLoadStartGuid || SelectedStatus.Id == InboundOffLoadEndGuid ||
                 SelectedStatus.Id == LoadCompleteGuid)
        {
            OdometerReadingVisible = true;
            IsBinCapturingVisible = true;
            SignaturePadVisible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            OdometerReadingVisible = false;
            IsEnabled = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("No Data", ex.Message, "Ok");
    }
}

I tested it by just setting the SignaturePadVisible to true in OnAppearing and then it does work so there isn't a problem regarding the front end of this page
I tested it by just setting the SignaturePadVisible to true in OnAppearing and then it does work so there isn't a problem regarding the front end of this page.

Is IsSignaturePadVisible Observable?

does SignaturePadVisible use the event from INotifyPropertyChanged?
